# How to do a loop in a loop and save it in a table in r

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, repeat

The problem is: If a teacher makes a bet with his class of 35 people "how many people have the same birthday?". If he loses the bet he pays $2, if he wins the bet, he gets $1. He did this bet 1137 times. So, I did a loop to represent this. Now, I want to repeat this test 1000 times and save it in a vector or table, so I can then run an inferential test on it. How do I repeat the loop?

````
```{r}

exact=c(seq(1:365), seq(1:365), seq(1:365), seq(1:366))  
bucket=numeric()  
smithbucks=0  
for(i in 1:1137){  
  class=sample(exact, size = 35, replace = TRUE)  
hmmm=sum(duplicated(class))  
if (hmmm > 0) smithbucks = smithbucks +1  
else smithbucks = smithbucks -2}  

```
````

Comment: I am trying to find out his average profits based on 1000 samplings

Comment: You've already simulated the bet 1,137 times, doesn't that give you the average profit you're after?

Comment: @sconfluentus It looks like all the brackets are there to me. The class sample is returning a vector of length 35, I'm not sure why you think it returns a single integer.

Comment: Not that you actually need a loop: The $1000$ examples can be taken from `3*rbinom(1000,1137,0.8143832)-2`

Answer (score 0):

Lots of ways to do it.  One simple way is to put it inside a sapply loop as such:

```
results <- sapply(1:1000, function(i) {
    exact=c(seq(1:365), seq(1:365), seq(1:365), seq(1:366))  
    smithbucks=0  
    for(i in 1:1137){  
      class=sample(exact, size = 35, replace = TRUE)  
    hmmm=sum(duplicated(class))  
    if (hmmm > 0) smithbucks = smithbucks +1  
    else smithbucks = smithbucks -2}
    return(smithbucks)
})
```

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I needed.